# Use shell script to copy a title tag in HTML file

Tags: html, shell, sh

I have two HTML files - `a.html` and `b.html`. I would like to replace the title tag in `b.html` with the one in `a.html`.

How would we do it using shell script? I know how to do a simple replacement in the same file by using `sed` command.

**a.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document AAAAA</title>
</head>
<body>
    This is Document A
</body>
</html>
```

**b.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document BBBB</title>
</head>
<body>
    This is Document B
</body>
</html>
```

**b.html - afer running the script** - Notice "Document BBBBB" is changed to "Document AAAAA"

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document AAAAA</title>
</head>
<body>
    This is Document B
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU `sed`:

```bash
title=`sed -n "s/^.*<title>\(.*\)<\/title>.*$/\1/p" a.html`; \
sed -i "s/^\(.*<title>\).*\(<\/title>.*\)$/\1$title\2/" b.html
```

BSD/OS X `sed`:

```bash
title=`sed -n "s/^.*<title>\(.*\)<\/title>.*$/\1/p" a.html`; \
sed -i '' "s/^\(.*<title>\).*\(<\/title>.*\)$/\1$title\2/" b.html
```

Essentially, it takes `a.html`, replaces the content with its title (`\1` group) and sets the result to the `title` variable.

Then with a very similar regex, it replaces the title in `b.html` with the variable and saves `b.html`.

Comment: Tested and it works as expected. Thanks for your explanation as well. Do you have any recommended resources to learn shell script and regex for beginner? Thanks

Comment: I won't pretend to be a shell scripting expert. It's just some past experience combined with stack overflow collective wisdom )

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i 's@BBBBB@AAAAA@' b.html
```

Does that work?

Comment: The example is a simplify version. I don't know what is in `a.html`